# Using Multiple Renderers in JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have data that I'd like to represent as a box and whiskers graph, and have set up a category plot to do so. However, in addition, I'd like to add a line chart that shows an accumulation of the averages for each data point.

Right now my code is something like this

```
DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset dataSet = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
int i = 0;
for (List<Integer> categoryList : categoryLists) {
    dataSet.add(categoryList, i, "BoxAndWhiskers");
    i++;
}
BoxAndWhiskerRenderer renderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();

double sum = 0;
i = 0;
DefaultCategoryDataset averageDataSet = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for (double average : averages) {
    sum += average;
    averageDataSet.add(sum, i, "Average");
    i++;
}
LineAndShapeRenderer lineAndShapeRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();


CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Type");
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Value");
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataSet, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);

plot.setDataset(1, averageDataSet);
plot.setRenderer(1, lineAndShapeRenderer);

JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(
    "Box-and-Whisker",
    new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 14),
    plot,
    true
);

BufferedImage outputImage = chart.createBufferedImage(800, 600);

ImageIO.write(outputImage, "png", new File("output.png"));
```

However, when I look at my output.png, I only see the box and whiskers render (no lineandshape graph).

Is there something else I need to do to use both renderers and datasets in my output image? Additionally, is there a better approach to getting a cumuluative line for the averages in my box and whiskers graph?

Comment: What happens when you plot `averageDataSet` by itself?

Comment: after looking at the output again, it appears as the a vertical set of dots is appearing in the center of my graph.

The two data sets will have the same key, so I guess i'm trying to figure out how to lay the points on top of the box and whiskers points properly

Comment: Try comparing the `rowKey` and `columnKey` in the two dataset `add()` invocations.

Comment: The rows for both datasets were the same, but the column is different.

If I want them to overlay  correctly, do they both need to be the same ?

Comment: As I recall, each `rowKey` is a series and each `columnKey` is an element in the series, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36172705/230513).

Comment: I'm using two datasets and two renderers though, would that make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to figure out how to lay the points on top of the box and whiskers points properly.

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36172705/230513) for `CategoryDataset`, each `rowKey` is a series and each `columnKey` is an element in the series. In the example below, the `"Mean"` row of `catData` includes an entry for each `columnKey` in `boxData`. Use `setDatasetRenderingOrder()` to specify `DatasetRenderingOrder`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DatasetRenderingOrder;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BoxAndWhiskerRenderer;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.LineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.statistics.DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38242696/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset boxData = new DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset();
        boxData.add(Arrays.asList(30, 36, 46, 55, 65, 76, 81, 80, 71, 59, 44, 34), "Planet", "Endor");
        boxData.add(Arrays.asList(22, 25, 34, 44, 54, 63, 69, 67, 59, 48, 38, 28), "Planet", "Hoth");
        BoxAndWhiskerRenderer boxRenderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
        DefaultCategoryDataset catData = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        catData.addValue(boxData.getMeanValue(0, 0), "Mean", boxData.getColumnKey(0));
        catData.addValue(boxData.getMeanValue(0, 1), "Mean", boxData.getColumnKey(1));
        LineAndShapeRenderer lineRenderer = new LineAndShapeRenderer();
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis("Type");
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Value");
        yAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);
        CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(boxData, xAxis, yAxis, boxRenderer);
        plot.setDataset(1, catData);
        plot.setRenderer(1, lineRenderer);
        plot.setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("Test", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(320, 480);
            }
        });
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Having code helped me visualize what you were saying :)

Comment: If you're curious, my problem was that i had the row and column switched around in my line graph, as i assumed they would be the same. Thanks again!!