# How to add duplicate items on X Axis in JFree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I would like to display duplicate items on X Axis as I have different values for that duplicate items which I want to compare. But the problem is that addValue() ignores the duplicate value. I have below code which I have written :

## Code

```
DefaultCategoryDataset my_bar_chart_dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for(int i=0;i <list1.size();i++)
{
     for(String checkelementID : checkelementIDs)
     {
         if(checkelementID.equals(list1.get(i).get(0)))
         {
              if(!list1.get(i).get(12).equals(""))
              {                         
                  my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(Double.parseDouble(list1.get(i).get(12)), "KEY",list1.get(i).get(1));
              }
         }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What has this got to do with SWT or eclipse-rcp?

Comment: I am using this chart into my eclipse rcp product

Comment: But there is nothing in this question that an expert on SWT or Eclipse RCP can answer so the tags are wrong.

Comment: I have modified tags.

Comment: You may be looking for multiple series, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36172705/230513). For more specific guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Multiple series but with duplicate name. As shown in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36171659/cast-defaultcategorydataset-to-categorydataset/36172705#36172705) , i need to display "Category 1" multiple time because I have duplicate names have unique values.